# Mobile orientation issue in HTML5 pages

Tags: html

I have done the HTML5 and angualrJS webpages. Its working fine in desktop and in the mobile device the landscape mode is not fit for my pages. So i want to restrict the webpage only for Portrait. Please any one can help me to resolve this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is supposed to happen when the user uses portrait mode?

Comment: My site is www.rgtohex.in . The design is looks good in the portrait mode. Thats why I'm preparing portrait mode also

Comment: OK, then what is supposed to happen when the user uses landscape mode?

Comment: I want restrict the page to support landscape mode... If the device in landscape mode the page will remain in the portrait mode

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You'll likely have to change the site so it looks somewhat ok in landscape mode, too.

Comment: Are you trying to keep the page from rotating as well, or just keep the same width / aspect ratio? If the former, you are stuck. If the latter, either set a `max-width` on your container or use `vw` units to keep relative sizes the same.